# How StringBuffer capacity works?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

My question is why after inserting 12 letters 'sb' capacity changes to 34? Why it remains 16 till 11 letters?

How is capacity concept working out here?

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();  
System.out.println(sb.capacity());//default 16  
sb.append("Hello");  
System.out.println(sb.capacity());//now 16  
sb.append("123456789ab");  
System.out.println(sb.capacity());//REMAINS 16
sb.append("123456789abc");
System.out.println(sb.capacity()); // NOW (16*2)+2=34 i.e (oldcapacity*2)+2
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your comments seem to answer your confusion.

Comment: Also, the page you took this code from also explains how the capacity works.

Comment: @ArvindSasikumar: Because the OP is wrong about how many characters have been inserted.  There's the five characters from `"Hello"` _plus_ the eleven characters from "123456789ab" _plus_ the twelve characters in `"123456789abc"`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks you pointed out correctly "append" OP is increasing length so it should be taken as 5+11=16 and when 5+12=17, that's when capacity gets increased by a set formula. Thanks again.